# Java multiple input

Tags: java

**UPDATED**
How can you by using this method (Collatz conjecture) to find the number with the highest number of operations between, say 4 and 230.
Any guidance appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Enter a low integer ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int low = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter a high integer ");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    maxendurance(number);
}

public static int maxendurance(int number) {

    int count = 0;

    System.out.print("The number " + number);
   // need to loop this i suppose in relative to user input
    while (number != 1) {
        number = (number & 1) != 0 ? number * 3 + 1 : number >> 1;
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(" has endurance: " + count);

    return number;
}
```

Comment: can you explain much more clear

Comment: This looks like you're trying to implement Collatz Conjecture?

Comment: Yes, im using Collatz Conjecture. And i need to apply that method on every number between user input low, and user input high (example. between 15 and 245034). And then find the number which had the highest number of operations before it reaches 1.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop through all the numbers between low and high. Look into `for`-loops:

```
for(int number = low; number <= high; number++)
{
   // do something with number
}
```

Somehow you will need to execute `a` for every number within the loop (hint: pass it in as a parameter). Then keep track of the number with the highest count.

Oh, and please name your methods more clearly than `a` and `b` - nobody will understand what they do without going through the code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, move the input out of method `a`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter an integer to be checked: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = input.nextInt();
    a(number);
    b();
}

public static int a(int number) {
    int count = 0;
    System.out.print("The number " + number);
    [...]
```

Then you can use a simple `for` loop to iterate between `low` and `high`:

```
int bestNumber = -1;
int bestScore = -1;
for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
    int score = a(i);
    if (score < bestScore) {
        bestNumber = i;
        bestScore = score;
    }
}
```

The result can then be found in `bestNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest a more advanced approach, in case relevant and incase anyone comes upon this. If you are concerned about **time efficiency**, Memoization or Dynamic Programming can help you, especially inverse dragon recursion.

I'll give you a hint. If you need more, just comment.

Take 3 for example. One transformation T has T(3)=10. If prior you had found it takes v transformations to take 10 to 1 and you stored (10,v) in a map, then instantly you know that it takes (v+1) steps to get 3 to 1.